# What are the best ways to defend against champions that deal true damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

What runes, masteries, items, or any other aspect of the game can help defend against targets that deal true damage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the true damage is your only concern, you should build health items and health regen, as well as Spell vamp or Lifesteal. Also, you could use crowd control effects like Stun or knock-ups to keep the enemy from being able to hit you. Short of all that, there's not much you can do against True Damage. Also, Exhaust does NOT reduce True Damage.

Comment: If you're worried about Vayne or Irelia you can also get attack speed reduction items such as Frozen Heart and Randuins as those champions true damage requires them to auto attack.

Comment: If you're worried about vayne, health actually hurts you... The attack slow is almost never enough and thornmail doesn't really do much either unfortunately... The best way to mitigate Vayne's true damage is to cc and focus her down before she can kill you. Otherwise, stacking health is by far the best counter to true damage.

Comment: @Lord_Mordoth building health against Vayne does not actually hurt you.  It makes her do slightly more damage per AA on average, but you live longer.  Wither her bolts maxed (8% true damage), an extra 1000 HP means she deals an extra 80 damage every third attack, or 80/3=26.66 extra damage per attack (average), which is pretty insignificant to your extra 1K HP.  You will die significantly slower than you would have before.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the kind of true damage that's being dealt and the champion dealing it.

For example, against olaf and irelia, you generally want more hp as well as AS reduction items like randuins or frozen heart, which incidentally reduces the physical portion of their attacks as well. These two champions are difficult to control in fights so either focus them down or kite them.

Against vayne, who deals % health true damage, get AS reduction items. Since vayne is relatively fragile, you can also aim to shut her out of fights by focusing her, either getting in her face and forcing her to leave, or use cc effects on her and kite if you don't have the chance to kill.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reduce true damage, but getting more hp, hp regen, and lifesteal/spell vamp helps against it, since buying resistances will not help reduce damage, but those stats will make the damage have less of an impact.

Answer (score 1):

Pure health like warmogs negate true damage.  However if the true damage is like Vayne, based off total health, then getting attack speed debuff like Frozen Heart, Randuins, and Exhaust will negate a lot of the damage you take from them.  The only item that builds against true damage in a way is Zhonya's Hourglass, but that is only for the 2 second active ability.